# hide all previous months start from the current month

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of months, now what I want is to hide all previous months start from the current month (march/MAR).

```
<ul id="months">
    <li><a class="li-month" data-val="0" href="#JAN">JAN</a></li>
    <li><a class="li-month" data-val="1" href="#FEB">FEB</a></li>
    <li><a class="li-month" data-val="2" href="#MAR">MAR</a></li>
    <li><a class="li-month" data-val="3" href="#APR">APR</a></li>
    <li><a class="li-month" data-val="4" href="#MAY">MAY</a></li>
    <li><a class="li-month" data-val="5" href="#JUN">JUN</a></li>
    <li><a class="li-month" data-val="6" href="#JULY">JULY</a></li>
    <li><a class="li-month" data-val="7" href="#AUG">AUG</a></li>
    <li><a class="li-month" data-val="8" href="#SEP">SEP</a></li>
    <li><a class="li-month" data-val="9" href="#OCT">OCT</a></li>
    <li><a class="li-month" data-val="10" href="#NOV">NOV</a></li>
    <li><a class="li-month" data-val="11" href="#DEC">DEC</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.li-month[href="#'+moment().format("MMM")+'"]').prevUntil().hide();
});
```

but unfortunately, not working, any ideas, help please?

Comment: `hide all previous months start from the current month` meaning this month to dec will be shown right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to use loops. Try following:

```
var month = new Date().getMonth();

$('#months').find('[data-val=' + month + ']').parent().prevAll().hide();
```

Looks a bit faster [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/loop-vs-find)

Comment: we cant use `:lt()` selector ?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var d = new Date();

n = d.getMonth();
console.log(n)
$('ul li').each(function() {
console.log($(this).find('a').attr('data-val'))
  if ($(this).find('a').attr('data-val') == n) {

    $(this).prevAll().hide();

  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="months">
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="0" href="#JAN">JAN</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="1" href="#FEB">FEB</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="2" href="#MAR">MAR</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="3" href="#APR">APR</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="4" href="#MAY">MAY</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="5" href="#JUN">JUN</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="6" href="#JULY">JULY</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="7" href="#AUG">AUG</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="8" href="#SEP">SEP</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="9" href="#OCT">OCT</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="10" href="#NOV">NOV</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="11" href="#DEC">DEC</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

DO it this way

Answer (score 3):

Here is your task. You forgot two things - 1) convert Mar to MAR and 2)go to upper level to get li
[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LKon18gsfGeRah9AB5Vj?p=preview)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.li-month[href="#'+moment().format("MMM").toUpperCase()+'"]').parent().prevUntil().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This one

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
         
    var d = new Date();
    var i=0;
    var n = d.getMonth();

     $('.li-month').hide(); 
          
         for(i =0; i < 13 ; i++){
           if( i > n || i > n ){
               $('[data-val="'+ (i -1) +'"]').show();  
             }
            else
             {
                 $('[data-val="'+ (i -1) +'"]').parent().hide();
              }
          }  
        });
```

```html
 

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <ul id="months">
            <li><a class="li-month" data-val="0" href="#JAN">JAN</a></li>
            <li><a class="li-month" data-val="1" href="#FEB">FEB</a></li>
            <li><a class="li-month" data-val="2" href="#MAR">MAR</a></li>
            <li><a class="li-month" data-val="3" href="#APR">APR</a></li>
            <li><a class="li-month" data-val="4" href="#MAY">MAY</a></li>
            <li><a class="li-month" data-val="5" href="#JUN">JUN</a></li>
            <li><a class="li-month" data-val="6" href="#JULY">JULY</a></li>
            <li><a class="li-month" data-val="7" href="#AUG">AUG</a></li>
            <li><a class="li-month" data-val="8" href="#SEP">SEP</a></li>
            <li><a class="li-month" data-val="9" href="#OCT">OCT</a></li>
            <li><a class="li-month" data-val="10" href="#NOV">NOV</a></li>
            <li><a class="li-month" data-val="11" href="#DEC">DEC</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Its not good to take static for loop, but accepted output so +1

Answer (score 2):

`new Date().getMonth()` returns a number between 0 and 11. Check if the `data-val` attr is less than current month and hide the parent `li`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var month = new Date().getMonth();

  $("#months > li > a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).data("val") < month) {
      $(this).parent().hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="months">
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="0" href="#JAN">JAN</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="1" href="#FEB">FEB</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="2" href="#MAR">MAR</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="3" href="#APR">APR</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="4" href="#MAY">MAY</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="5" href="#JUN">JUN</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="6" href="#JULY">JULY</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="7" href="#AUG">AUG</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="8" href="#SEP">SEP</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="9" href="#OCT">OCT</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="10" href="#NOV">NOV</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="li-month" data-val="11" href="#DEC">DEC</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `.parent()` and `.prevUntil()` as shown :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var month = new Date().getMonth();
    $('.li-month[data-val="'+ month +'"]').parent().prevUntil().hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/sz3zznav/2/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var myDate = new Date();
    var curMonth = myDate.getMonth();
    alert(curMonth);
    $('.li-month:lt('+curMonth+')').parent('li').hide();
});
</script>
```